# Why is there a "topic" parameter in the overridden serialize() method from Serializer<> interface in org.apache.kafka.common.serialization

Tags: java, serialization, apache-kafka

I have observed that implementations of the method  serialize() of the Serializer<> interface has two parameters:

byte[] serialize(String topic, T data)

but the method body does not require String topic parameter at all. So why does it exist?

Sample Implementation available in the package org.apache.kafka.common.serialization:

```
@Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, String data) {
        try {
            if (data == null)
                return null;
            else
                return data.getBytes(encoding);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new SerializationException("Error when serializing string to byte[] due to unsupported encoding " + encoding);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The interface method signature requires it. Doesn't mean it needs to be used by that specific implementation... Any inherited Java method works the same way, so not sure how this is a Kafka question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific implementation, indeed there's no usage.
Yet, this parameter may be used by different / advanced Serializers.